# Where do you change the rate that the IIS app pool automatically recycles?

Tags: iis-7, application-pools

While I can say I've manually recycled an app pool or two (or thousand) in my day, I don't know much about how this occurs automatically.

I assume that after a certain time interval the app pool automatically recycles, but I don't know what that time period is or how to change it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The default is 29 hours. You change it to a different interval, or at different milestones than a time interval, via the properties of the application pool. Right-click on the pool, go to Properties, and review the options there.

Comment: In IIS7, it's not a right-click per se, but it's there just the same.  Under the Advanced and Recycling settings for the app pool are where they can be set.  The other two to watch for are recycling when memory has been exceeded and the default 20 minute idle shutdown.  Unless it's for bulk hosting, the 20 minute idle shutdown should be disabled.

Comment: Cool - i haven't gotten much of any time on IIS 7.

Comment: Thanks for the great answer, quick question: Is there any other way to access this besides the application pool?

Comment: It's a setting *of* the app pool, where else would you set it? You can also set it via vbscript or powershell, but either way, it's a property of a given app pool.